# have issue converting '09-JUN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM' to datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have been trying to convert `'09-JUN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM'` to `'2014-06-09 23:11:00'`

I have tried two methods:

```py
dk = datetime.strptime( '09-JUN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM', '%D-%M-%Y %H.%M.%S.F')

dk = pd.to_datetime('09-JUN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM','%DD-%MON-%RR %HH.%MI.%SS.%FF %AM')
```

I'm not able to convert it to date time

I wanted to have in format like

2014-04-01 00:11:00

Comment: Please review the question. There are multiple output values specified (`2014-06-09 23:11:00`, `2014-04-01 00:11:00`) and neither can be achieved by reformatting the input value `09-JUN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM`.

Comment: You also have some basic mistakes, like to start, `F` instead of `%f` (although `datetime` only handles up to microseconds, so it doesn't work) and no format code for "AM" in the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want something like this:

```
import datetime

a = datetime.datetime.strptime('09-JUN-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM', '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f000 %p')
print(a)
```

Result:
`2014-06-09 00:00:00`

With datetime parsing, you've just gotta do trial and error until it starts parsing stuff correctly.  And you have to *read the manual.* Abbreviated month is different from numeric month.  Just like 2 digit year is different than 4 digit year.  Milliseconds expects 6 digits, so you have to add the trailing 000 for your example.

A quick google and you'll pull up 4 different websites with quick how-tos and summary docs on strptime.  For example:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-strptime-with-milliseconds-in-python/

Comment: This'll only work if the nanoseconds are always 000. Pandas, on the other hand, supports nanoseconds.